# Create datatable based on cell selection of another datatable in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app with 2 datables.

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
              ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3"),
               br(),
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot5")
             )
           )))
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

   DF= data.frame(Sel. = rep(TRUE,2),
               Label=paste("Test",as.integer(1:2)),
               Marg=rep("Marg1",2),
               Avail.=as.integer(rep.int(50,2)),
               Sel =as.integer(rep.int(50,2)),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    DF,
    selection=list(mode="single", target="cell")
  )
    output$hot5 <-DT::renderDataTable({
      DF = data.frame(
        Sel= rep(TRUE, as.numeric(input$hot3_cells_selected)),
        Id= 1:as.numeric(input$hot3_cells_selected),
        Label=paste("Item",as.integer(1:as.numeric(input$hot3_cells_selected))),
        Pf=as.integer(rep.int(0,as.numeric(input$hot3_cells_selected))),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      DF
    })


}
```

What I want to achieve is when I click on the "Avail" cell (50) to create a new data frame with 50 rpws which will be displayed in a new data table.
[image]

but I take as error

```
Error in rep: invalid 'times' argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown by the `rep` function since you don't provide a valid `times` argument. In this case, `input$hot3_cells_selected` returns a vector representing the row and column indices of the selected cell, respectively. You can access the actual content of the cell using:

```
DF[input$hot3_cells_selected]
```

However, you need some additional adjustments to make your code more robust. For example, `input$hot3_cells_selected` is empty until a cell is selected, which will cause a similar problem with the `rep` function. Or, your should cover the case where a non-numeric cell is selected (i.e *Test1* or *Marg1*). Below is a possible naïve solution:

```
# changing only this part of the code will be enough
# inserted DF[input$hot3_cells_selected] when needed below
output$hot5 <-DT::renderDataTable({
    # checking whether any cell is selected or not
    if(length(input$hot3_cells_selected) > 0) {
      # checking whether the selected cell includes a number or not
      # note that suppressWarnings is optional
      if(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(DF[input$hot3_cells_selected])))) {
        # you don't need to store the data frame, so removed the assignment
        # even if you wanna store it for future reference, use a unique name (not DF)
        data.frame(
          Sel= rep(TRUE, as.numeric(DF[input$hot3_cells_selected])),
          Id= 1:as.numeric(DF[input$hot3_cells_selected]),
          Label=paste("Item",as.integer(1:as.numeric(DF[input$hot3_cells_selected]))),
          Pf=as.integer(rep.int(0,as.numeric(DF[input$hot3_cells_selected]))),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      }
    }
  })
```